# Laravel 8 on AS400 using ODBC table names with dots

Tags: php, db2, odbc, laravel-8

I am on a project where I need to retrieve information from a table that contains a "." in it's name... My query looks like this:

```
$data['scale'] = DB::connection('odbc')
->table('QS36F."CF.STYL1"')
->select('SSCALE','SINTDE')
->where('STYLE#', 'LIKE', $style.'%')
->get();
```

Obviously the above is not working and returns

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: [IBM][System i
> Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0113 - Name """CF" not allowed.
> (SQLPrepare[0] at
> /home/calvin/rpmbuild/BUILD/php-8.0.8/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_driver.c:203)
> (SQL: select "SSCALE", "SINTDE" from "QS36F"."""CF"."STYL1""" where
> "STYLE#" LIKE 1981USD%)

I could probably get it to work using a full raw query but if there's anyway to make it work using normal eloquent functions, I would definitely prefer using table() select() where() get() ect ....

Any suggestions?

Comment: QS36F."CF.STYL1" - maybe problem in "?

Comment: Can you share what laravel package you used?

Comment: I am using PHPCommunityPlus+ on the as400 with dual DB2 and ODBC provided by seidengroup.com when you ask for it. And for the ODBC driver in Laravel I am using yoramdelangen/laravel-pdo-odbc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I solved this using DB::raw() like this:

```
$data['scale'] = DB::connection('odbc')
->table(DB::raw('QS36F."CF.STYL1"'))
->select('SSCALE','SINTDE')
->where('STYLE#', 'LIKE', $style.'%')
->get();
```

At least this way I am not using a full raw query. I hope that will help the next guy that needs to deal with table names containing dots lol